# Showing a control based on type of databound viewmodel?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm learning WPF at the moment. I'm finding xaml quite tough to use. I have `MainWindow.xaml` defined like this:

```
<Window x:Class="Compliance.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="MainWindow.Resources.xaml"></ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And `MainWindow.Resources.xaml` like this:

```
<ResourceDictionary 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:Compliance.ViewModel"
    xmlns:vw="clr-namespace:Compliance.View">

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:Entities.AbstractEntityViewModel}">
        <vw:AbstractEntityView></vw:AbstractEntityView>     
    </DataTemplate>        
</ResourceDictionary>
```

`AbstractEntityView` is like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Compliance.View.AbstractEntityView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <StackPanel>
        <Label Content="ID:"></Label>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=EntityId}"></TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Then in `App.xaml.cs` I am overriding `OnStartup` like this:

```
MainWindow window = new MainWindow();

    //Model class
Individual ind = new Individual(1,"Name");

    //subclass of AbstractEntityViewModel
var vm = new Entities.IndividualEntityViewModel(ind);

window.DataContext = vm;
window.Show();
```

However, nothing appears in the window.

I used the answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5471982/how-can-i-display-my-user-control-in-the-mainwindow) to get my control to render. However, this requires you to refer to elements in the view from the code, which I don't want to do.

Is it possible to get a window to pick a View to render based on the ViewModel set as its datacontext? Or do I have the wrong idea about how MVVM is supposed to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right idea, but you're not actually telling WPF to display your `ViewModel` anywhere

I usually host a `ViewModel` in a `ContentControl` object if I am binding to a single ViewModel

```
<Window x:Class="Compliance.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="MainWindow.Resources.xaml"></ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding }" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The `ContentControl` is usually not needed for lists of `Models` or `ViewModels`, since the object is automatically inserted as the `Content` property of the `ContentPresenter` of each item. For example, no `ContentControl` is needed when binding a `ListBox` to a collection of `ViewModels`

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollectionOfViewModel}" />
```

Comment: Neat, thanks. I got a weird problem for while with the line `DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"` that turned up in my window definition (I'm sure I didn't put it there...) but everything worked once I removed that.

Comment: @Oliver Referring to `Self` in the binding will set the binding source to the UI object, not it's `DataContext`